# Create a sparse matrix from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix, minimum-spanning-tree

I am doing a school project where I am given an undirected graph G, and am supposed find the minimum spanning tree within G. I figured I´d use minimum_spanning_tree from Scipy [(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.minimum_spanning_tree.html)](http://Scipy). But to do that I have to feed it an array_like or sparse matrix, 2 dimensions.
Like so:

```
x_right=
    ([[0, 2, 0],
    [2, 0, 5],
    [0, 5, 0]])
```

In the project, I am supposed to take in an adjacency list structured like this:

```
x_input=
    {'A': [('B', 2)],
     'B': [('A', 2), ('C', 5)], 
     'C': [('B', 5)]}
```

To give it a try... there is, to see if the minimum_spanning_tree was giving my desired result, I ran it by manually changing the the x_input to x_right and I got the output as:

```
(0, 1)    2.0
(1, 2)    5.0
```

Which is what I want but I am supposed to return the output in the same format as x_input.

I've been trying out all sorts of methods (one of them DictVectorizer - ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'B'... like in other cases) for to long and I think it is time to seek help.

So to boil it down, do you have suggestions about how I can create a matrix suitable for the minimum_spanning_tree from the x_input (and how I can convert the result to x_input format again).

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if I understand the question completely. From what I get is that you want to convert `x_input` to sparse matrix `x_right`

```
import scipy.sparse as sp

x_input= {'A': [('B', 2)],
          'B': [('A', 2), ('C', 5)], 
          'C': [('B', 5)]}

keys = x_input.keys()
map_dict = dict(zip(list(keys), range(len(keys))))
```

I create dictionary keys to map value to index above e.g. from `A` to `1` and `B` to `2`. Then, you can loop through the given dictionary in order to get row/column position. Afterward, you can convert row/column pair of the matrix with corresponding values to sparse matrix.

```
rows, cols, vals = [], [], []
for key, values in x_input.items():
    for value in values:
        rows.append(map_dict[key])
        cols.append(map_dict[value[0]])
        vals.append(value[1])
X = sp.csr_matrix((vals, (rows, cols)))
```

**Output** is as follows:

```
print(X.toarray())
array([[0, 2, 0],
       [2, 0, 5],
       [0, 5, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

**To convert sparse matrix back**, easy way is to convert sparse CSR matrix to COO matrix. COO matrix allows you to get row, column and data easily. After getting the row/column positions, I have dictionary `map_dict_reverse` to convert those back to the given keys.

```
from collections import defaultdict
map_dict_reverse = dict(zip(range(len(keys)), list(keys)))

Xcoo = X.tocoo() # convert csr matrix to coo sparse matrix
x_convert = defaultdict(list)
for (r, c, d) in zip(Xcoo.row, Xcoo.col, Xcoo.data):
    x_convert[map_dict_reverse[r]].append((map_dict_reverse[c] , d))
x_convert = dict(x_convert)
```

You will get `x_input` back at the end.

```
{'A': [('B', 2)], 'B': [('A', 2), ('C', 5)], 'C': [('B', 5)]}
```

Comment: You got it exactly right (reading it now, it is a bit confusing). Thank you for the reply.

Comment: Yeah, there is a lot of tiny stuff happening! Feel free to take your time to ingest it.